# check if integer value inside a string list with Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

I am writing a stored procedure and I need to check if an integer variable value is inside a list.

I tried like this

```
If (var_int1 in (4,6,9) ) then ....
```

This work but the list of numbers will return to me from a varchar field so is there a way to still use `IN` and without using a temporary table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the builtin function [position](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-position.html):

```
if(position(val IN valList) > 0)then
```

Note that you need to avoid false positives where only part of the number matches, ie given the values `'123,456,789'` position for `'2'` would return true which you probably don't want. To avoid that you could add comma (as you have comma separated values in the varchar field) as prefix and suffix to your search strings, ie

```
val = ',' || cast(var_int1 as varchar(10)) || ',';
valList = ',' || valList || ',';
if(position(val IN valList) > 0)then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide another possible solution:

```
valList = '2,3,4';  --- varchar
val = 3;  --- integer

if ( valList like '%'||val||'%' ) then ...
```

Comment: What if valList='2,33,4' ?